# WPF Binding to Radio Buttons If Radio Buttons duplicated to same property .,.,. not updating the Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

[image: Main View]

Here This is the View which the Radio buttons had been bound to a Enum Property using IValueConverter(Works Fine)

if I duplicate these radio Buttons as Below XAML

```
 <Grid.Resources>
            <l:enumBoolConverter x:Key="ebc" />
            <l:EnumStringConverter x:Key="es" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel>
                <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding YesOrNo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ebc}, ConverterParameter=Yes}">Yes</RadioButton>
                <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding YesOrNo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ebc}, ConverterParameter=No}">No</RadioButton>
                <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding YesOrNo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ebc}, ConverterParameter=Maybe}">Maybe</RadioButton>
                <Separator />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding YesOrNo, Converter={StaticResource es}, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel>
                <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding YesOrNo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ebc}, ConverterParameter=Yes}">Yes</RadioButton>
                <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding YesOrNo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ebc}, ConverterParameter=No}">No</RadioButton>
                <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding YesOrNo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ebc}, ConverterParameter=Maybe}">Maybe</RadioButton>
                <Separator />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding YesOrNo, Converter={StaticResource es}, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
```

I can do Changing option From "Yes" to "No" but While am changing From "No" to "Yes" there is the problem which the property or view will not be updated..

Why..

I guess it,, for the second radio button of the "No" Option was once again called to Set the property "YesOrNo" while I am changing the First to "Yes"

is it so.. ??? What is the Resolution to Operate both the group... to one property.. and get updated on all the bindings.. ?

**The CS Code for Value Convertions**

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(YesOrNoOptions), typeof(bool))]
    class enumBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var ps = parameter as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ps))
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(YesOrNoOptions), value))
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

            var param = Enum.Parse(value.GetType(), ps);

            var ret = param.Equals(value);

            return ret;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var ps = parameter as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ps))
            {
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            }
            return Enum.Parse(targetType, ps);
        }
    }

    [ValueConversion(typeof(YesOrNoOptions), typeof(string))]
    internal class EnumStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Enum v = (Enum)value;
            return v.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**CS Code of ViewModel**

```
public enum YesOrNoOptions
    {
        Yes,
        No,
        Maybe
    }
    public class DemDC : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public DemDC()
        {
            _yt = YesOrNoOptions.Yes;
        }
        public YesOrNoOptions _yt;
        public YesOrNoOptions YesOrNo
        {
            get
            {
                return _yt;
            }
            set
            {
                _yt = value;
                Notify("YesOrNo");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void Notify(string pname)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pname));
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance...

Any how the logic should be same for all the views isn't it?

While coming from "yes" to "No" both the panels are updated fine.. 
but while going back to "Yes" from "No" it stays there in the "No" option itself..

because the second radio button is setting the "No" value to enum... ??? while operating "Yes" isn't it???

if this is happening..? Why it is not happening while choosing from "Yes" to "No" ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To circumvent this issue you can disable property changes while the property is being updated:

```
private bool suppress;
private YesOrNoOptions _yt;
public YesOrNoOptions YesOrNo
{
    get
    {
        return _yt;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_yt != value && !suppress)
        {
            _yt = value;
            suppress = true;
            Notify("YesOrNo");
            suppress = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: we have to suppress because to avoid property writing call by the second radio button ... isn't. it?? thank you so much @Adi Lester